# Compare three sets of experimental data (Acid-Base titration)?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, agreement-statistics

Using acid-base titration technique for 20 different batches of salt samples (samples are exactly same, batches are different), the residual impurities (in ppm, microgram per gram of salt) were determined using 3 different indicators. Data are given below

```
# Experimental "Bromophenol blue" "Bromocresol green"    "Methyl red + bromocresol green" 
# First column : Batch number 
# Unit of 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns : ppm (micrograms per gram of salt) 
1                    72                  30              15
2                    64                  25              15
3                    44                  15              15
4                    48                  28              24
5                    73                  20              30
6                    2                   10              7
7                    2                   6               2
8                    9                   5               7
9                    65                  133             44
10                   51                  136             45
11                   46                  81              40
12                   52                  92              46
13                   48                  127             42
14                   52                  46              46
15                   49                  86              43
16                   51                  90              44
17                   50                  45              88
18                   49                  88              86
19                   47                  83              41
20                   48                  43              42
```

I want to know how can we determine which two data are statistically in agreement with each other. It appears that the 2nd and 4th column data are in good agreement but the question is, "Statistically how much?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know if there are some methods differences seen in the three different analysis results from the same batch. First plot the data:

[image]

I names the three variables `X, Y, Z`. It is clear from the plot that there is some systematic disagreement, the red points (`X`) are highest for the first batches and then lowest for the last batches ... that would be an interaction effect.

We can fit a two-way anova for the data:

```
mod.anova <- aov(impure_ppm  ~ factor(Batch) + variable, data=titrelong)
summary(mod.anova)

              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
factor(Batch) 19  31659  1666.3   2.901 0.00255 **
variable       2   5490  2744.8   4.778 0.01409 * 
Residuals     38  21828   574.4
```

with clear results. It is not possible to fit a full interaction term, since this is a model without replication, the 38 df for residual is the same as the full interaction term.